# Determine the order of data by solving inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

My teacher gave me a homework which I do not know how to solve efficiently. Consider the vector $\mathbf{v} = (-1,1,c,-c,-1+c,1+c,-1-c,1-c)$ with a $c > 0$ constant. The task is to determine all possible orderings of $v_1, v_2,...,v_8$ at different $c$ values (order means here increasing order of the vector entries). Could you please help me how to solve this task?

Comment: Which inefficient way did you find?

Comment: The inefficient way is to check the cases $c > 2$, $2 \ge c > 1$, $1  \ge c > 1/2$, and $c < 1/2$.

Comment: Your "inefficient" way doesn't look too bad. You could also try graphing these expressions with $c$ as the horizontal axis variable.